# Which license should I use in the program?

Tags: licensing, copyright

I have developed software that I would like to sell commercially. I don't know which license I should use. I've never used one before. I don't I think need/should to write one myself. Basically, I want to restrict end-used from doing these things without contacting me first:

- share binary program with others
- (re-)sell the software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to allow your users to make copies and you don't want to share your code, the default copyright is sufficient.

Just put in your copyright statement

> Copyright 2014, Jack.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Copying of this program is only allowed with prior permission from the author.

It might not be legally possible to prohibit reselling (if someone passes their single copy on, without keeping a copy of the software).